# Is it possible to imagine a virtual displacement for a simple pendulum?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

Because I could not understand the term "virtual displacement" properly I have too much questions with it. I will be helpful with your answer. My question:

Can we imagine a virtual displacement for a simple pendulum? Is it possible to have virtual displacement for the system?

If yes: then what will be its virtual displacement?

If No: Give an example where virtual displacement is possible.

Comment: More on [virtual displacement](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+virtual+displacement*).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If the pendulum is at an angle $\theta$ to the vertical, imagine changing  $\theta$ to $\theta+\delta \theta$.

Here is an example of how to use a virtual displacement: Consider a bubble of radius $R$ with an excess pressure $P$ compared to outside, and with surface tension $T$. In equilibrium there are no unbalanced forces, so if some small change $dR$ in the radius occurs there will be be no work done. But the work done will be
$$
\delta W=Td(Area)-Pd(Volume)\\
=T d(4\pi R^2)-P d(4/3\pi R^3)\\
=8\pi T RdR -4\pi P R^2 dR\\\
= 4\pi(2TR- P R^2)dR\\
=4\pi R(2T-PR)dR
$$
This has to be zero, so $P= 2T/R$ ---- the well-known formula for  the excess pressure in a bubble.

Comment: How can it be virtual displacement as change in $\theta$ causing change in both constrained force $T$ and external force? And time is also changing how infinitesimally less it may be.

Comment: You are clearly confused, let me add an example to my answer.